# Prevent Two Microservice Instances Reading The Same Document

Tags: mongodb, microservices

I have two instances of the same microservice running. These microservices reference a mongodb collection using the reactivemongo library. This mongodb collection is simulating a queue. So each microservice picks off the latest item in the queue and then processes it (can't change this design as that is what the company have come up with and they don't want to change).

I am concerned about two instances picking of (ie reading) the same element in the queue and then begin processing on it. They said that can't happen due to the atomicity properties of mongodb. But to me, atomic operations mean that the database operation will either happen fully or not at all. So how would that help in this scenario that I am describing? I don't think it does.

They also said that each instance when it tries to read a document for processing, if it finds one, it then updates the status from Todo to In-Progress. They said this means that if another instance comes along it won't pick up the same document as the status is not in Todo anymore.

It seems like what they are saying is that during this atomic operation of updating the document's status from ToDo to In-Progress, no other instance can read that same row even if the update hasn't happened yet due to atomicity. Is that how mongodb works?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo DB supports document-level locking so you can basically lock a row so that other service does not pick it up. Reference documentation is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/).

Another solution could be to use the operation [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)(), which enables you to atomically modify a document. This is a bit slower but does the trick. So you can mark the document in progress using findAndModify so that other service will not pick up. It will work because your find condition will only have TO-DO.

e.g.

```
var doc = db.runCommand({
              "findAndModify" : "COLLECTION_NAME",
              "query" : {"_id": "ID_DOCUMENT", "status" : "TO_DO"},
              "update" : {"$set" : {"status" : "IN_PROGRESS"} }
}).value
```

Comment: so are you saying that mongodb's atomic semantics are that once one thread has found the document no other thread can get a lock on it?

Comment: yes checkout the concurrency control here- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Comment: let me know if you agree with the post.

Comment: is there any operation like `findAndModifyMany()`? What is the solution in this case. Multiple instances need to read multiple different documents and I need to be sure there is no repetitive documents.